# Workload Manager for Windows based HPC with GPU

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm

We have an HPC environment on a Windows server in AWS. We would like to share the computing capability with multiple users. I am not aware of any workload manager or scheduler for the windows environment. I know about SLURM but it is not compatible with Windows.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

HTCondor supports windows workflow management. https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/